# Receiving type errors with Either return type

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I am working on rewriting an older app using TypeScript and fp-ts. I created a validation function but am running into several type errors. I am not sure where the problem could be or why it is taking the return values and trying to convert to an `Either` wrapped inside an `Either`.

1. Why am I getting the type errors?
2. How can I fix or resolve the type errors?
3. What should I do coding-wise in the function space to ensure I can greatly minimize this issue in the future?

```js
   const validateRegistrationForm = (user: User): Either<Error, User> => {
    return E.tryCatch(
        async () => {
            const schema = Joi.object().keys({
                userName: Joi.string().min(4).max(255).required(),
                firstName: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i)).min(1).max(50).required(),
                lastName: Joi.string().pattern(new RegExp(/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i)).min(1).max(50).required(),
                emailAddress: Joi.string().email().required(),
                password: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number()).required(),
                confirmPassword: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.number()).disallow(Joi.ref('password')).required(),
                profilePicUrl: Joi.string().uri({scheme: [/https?/]})
            });

            // If post exists, wrap it in a 'some', otherwise return 'none'
            let {error} = await schema.validateAsync(user);

            return error && error.length > 0 ? E.left({name: "ValidationError", message: error.message}) : E.right(user);
        },
        (reason: Error) => E.left(new Error(String(reason)))  // convert reasons to Error objects for consistency
    );
}
```

```
error TS2322: Type 'Either<Either<Error, never>, Promise<Right<User> | Left<{ name: string; message: any; }>>>' is not assignable to type 'Either<Error, User>'.
   Type 'Left<Either<Error, never>>' is not assignable to type 'Either<Error, User>'.
    Type 'Left<Either<Error, never>>' is not assignable to type 'Left<Error>'.
      Type 'Either<Error, never>' is not assignable to type 'Error'.
        Type 'Left<Error>' is missing the following properties from type 'Error': name, message

return E.tryCatch(
```